# SASS animation (not SCSS) is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, spinner

Good afternoon! I try to make an animation for spinner which is rendered via React, but it doesn't want to work in SASS. In SCSS it works properly. I've tried to do it in many ways but still don't have a solution. The spinner displays, but doesn't move. If somebody has an idea, I kindly ask to share with me.

There is a code:

```
   <div>
     <svg className="spinner" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
         <path d="M 2 50 A 48 48 0 0 0 98 50 L 2 50" className="-ring1" />
         <path d="M 98 50 A 48 48 0 0 0 2 50 L 98 50" className="-ring2"/>
         <circle fill="black" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
     </svg>
   </div>  

@keyframes spinner-loading
 0%
 transform: rotateZ(0deg)
 100%
 transform: rotateZ(359deg) 

.spinner
 margin-top: 20%
 margin-left: 30%
 height: 30%
 width: 30%
 animation: spinner-loading 1.5s linear infinite

.-ring1 
 fill: white

.-ring2 
 fill: rgba(white, 0.2)
```

And there is a SCSS's version:

```
@keyframes spinner-loading {
 0%{
 transform: rotateZ(0deg);
 }

 100%{
 transform: rotateZ(359deg);
  }
 }
.spinner {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  animation: spinner-loading 1.5s linear infinite;
 }

.-ring1 {
 fill: red;
}

.-ring2 {
 fill: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Sass convert** https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-convert to convert from and to the different formats (scss, sass, css) so you can convert scss working file to sass and compare with the one you wrote to check what is wrong.

Looking at it and if you are saying it works with scss which uses `{}` to limit the rules it can be a indenting problem with your keyframes rules:

```
@keyframes spinner-loading
 0%
   transform: rotateZ(0deg)
 100%
   transform: rotateZ(359deg) 

.spinner
 margin-top: 20%
 margin-left: 30%
 height: 30%
 width: 30%
 animation: spinner-loading 1.5s linear infinite

.-ring1 
 fill: white

.-ring2 
 fill: rgba(white, 0.2)
```

Comment: Yes, it works properly in SCSS syntax, but in SASS it doesn't. I converted it and received the same variant as you presented above and as it was used before. Do you mean that the problem in the SASS's syntax?

Comment: Yes, the Sass syntax is indent based and an error with that could present issues.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how to make this animation in SASS? I suppose if the problem in syntax, it's going to be another way of ealization.                      P.S. I added the SCSS's version to my post. As I've told it works properly.